# Compare enum indexes of two SQL entries

Tags: mysql, sql, enums

I need to compare the index of two enum values from two similar columns in two different tables.  The enum values are `New, Reviewed, Design, Production`, and are in ascending order of status in our process, so it should be relatively easy to do a compare based on the idea that`New == 1`, `Reviewed==2`, etc...

I am currently trying:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN table1.review_status < table2.review_status THEN table1.review_status
            WHEN table2.review_status < table1.review_status THEN table2.review_status
            END
```

This seems to be doing an alphabetical compare on the strings `NEW`, `REVIEW`, etc...  I need it to compare the index, not the value.  Is this possible?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 0 to the enum value to convert it to a number for numeric comparison.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

```
create table table1 (
  id int,
  review_status enum('New', 'Reviewed', 'Design', 'Production')
);
insert into table1 values
(1, 'New'), (2, 'Production'), (3, 'Design'), (4, 'Reviewed');

create table table2 (
  id int,
  review_status enum('New', 'Reviewed', 'Design', 'Production')
);
insert into table2 values
(1, 'Design'), (2, 'New'), (3, 'Reviewed'), (4, 'Reviewed');

select table1.id, table1.review_status s1, table2.review_status s2,
  CASE WHEN table1.review_status+0 < table2.review_status THEN table1.review_status
       WHEN table2.review_status+0 < table1.review_status THEN table2.review_status
  END
from table1
join table2 on table2.id = table1.id;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/906529/4

Answer (score 1):

Make a new table. Call it something like ReviewStatusDefinitions. The table will have two columns: StatusName and StatusOrder. The StatusName column will have values for "New", "Reviewed", etc, and the StatusOrder column will have the corresponding numeric values 1, 2, etc. Now you can just join to this table and use the StatusOrder column for your CASE.

Comment: This sounds like a legit answer, but I'm very new to MySQL.  Could you maybe break this down a bit more?